# Colors that work well with beamer color scheme albatross

Tags: beamer, color

Is there a color scheme made using `\definecolor` that defines colors that work well with the beamer color scheme albatross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better check out the source code of color theme albatross, in file `beamercolorthemealbatross.sty` (which is usually located at `your TEXMF root/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/`).